# comparing between two arraylists and remove extra element from there

Tags: android, arraylist

how do I compare two arraylists?

I have a sdCoverList array and thumbnailList array.

```
02-04 11:05:05.210: I/System.out(4035): HASHED THUMBNAIL[-2122410790, 2043473787, 1914391068, 1785308349, 1656225630, 1527142911, 1398060192, 1268977473, 1139894754, 1010812035, 1242943301, 1113860582, 984777863, 855695144, 726612425, 597529706, 468446987, 339364268, 210281549]
02-04 11:05:05.210: I/System.out(4035): SD COVER LIST[-2122410790, 2043473787, 1914391068, 1785308349, 1268977473, 1656225630, 1527142911, 1139894754, 1398060192, 1010812035, 1242943301, 1113860582, 984777863, 855695144, 726612425, 597529706, 468446987, 339364268, 210281549, 717409028]
```

In my sd cover list, i have an extra value that i want to remove away but first i'd have to compare with thumbnailList array first. if both have the same elements, don't do anything but if theres an extra, remove it from sd card.

My array lists

for sdCoverList:

```
// CHECK DIRECTORY BEFORE DELETING THEM
            File strPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + folderName+"/Covers");
            File yourDir = new File(strPath, "");
            if(yourDir.length()!=0)
            for (File f : yourDir.listFiles()) {
                if (f.isFile())
                {
                    String name = f.getName();
                    sdCoverList.add(name);
                    //System.out.println(sdCoverList);
                }
```

for hashedthumbnail

```
for (int a=0;a<=thumbnailList.size()-1;a++)
        {
            String hashed = String.valueOf(thumbnailList.get(a).hashCode());
            Log.d("hashed",hashed);
            hashedThumbnail.add(hashed);
        }
```

Comment: a nice answer is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/919420/1265724)

Comment: if i already have an arraylist, how do i use collection with it?

Comment: @Ramkiran hi, i have edited my codes above

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
List<String> sdCoverList = new ArrayList<String>();
sdCoverList.add("-2122410790");
sdCoverList.add("2043473787");
sdCoverList.add("717409028");

List<String> hashedThumbnail = new ArrayList<String>();
hashedThumbnail.add("-2122410790");
hashedThumbnail.add("2043473787");

System.out.println("sdCover List: " + sdCoverList);
System.out.println("hashedThumbnail List: " + hashedThumbnail);


List<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
temp.addAll(sdCoverList);
temp.removeAll(hashedThumbnail);

System.out.println("temp List: " + temp);

sdCoverList.removeAll(temp);

System.out.println("sdCover List: " + sdCoverList);
```

The output will be

```
sdCover List: [-2122410790, 2043473787, 717409028]
hashedThumbnail List: [-2122410790, 2043473787]
temp List: [717409028]
sdCover List: [-2122410790, 2043473787]
```

Comment: i have more then 50000 records in array if i am tring to addAll and removeAll Application Stuck in that case what i do??