# Java 8: performance of Streams vs Collections

Tags: java, performance, collections, java-8, java-stream

I'm new to Java 8. I still don't know the API in depth, but I've made a small informal benchmark to compare the performance of the new Streams API vs the good old Collections.

The test consists in filtering a list of `Integer`, and for each even number, calculate the square root and storing it in a result `List` of `Double`.

Here is the code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Calculating square root of even numbers from 1 to N       
        int min = 1;
        int max = 1000000;

        List<Integer> sourceList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = min; i < max; i++) {
            sourceList.add(i);
        }

        List<Double> result = new LinkedList<>();


        //Collections approach
        long t0 = System.nanoTime();
        long elapsed = 0;
        for (Integer i : sourceList) {
            if(i % 2 == 0){
                result.add(Math.sqrt(i));
            }
        }
        elapsed = System.nanoTime() - t0;       
        System.out.printf("Collections: Elapsed time:\t %d ns \t(%f seconds)%n", elapsed, elapsed / Math.pow(10, 9));


        //Stream approach
        Stream<Integer> stream = sourceList.stream();       
        t0 = System.nanoTime();
        result = stream.filter(i -> i%2 == 0).map(i -> Math.sqrt(i)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        elapsed = System.nanoTime() - t0;       
        System.out.printf("Streams: Elapsed time:\t\t %d ns \t(%f seconds)%n", elapsed, elapsed / Math.pow(10, 9));


        //Parallel stream approach
        stream = sourceList.stream().parallel();        
        t0 = System.nanoTime();
        result = stream.filter(i -> i%2 == 0).map(i -> Math.sqrt(i)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        elapsed = System.nanoTime() - t0;       
        System.out.printf("Parallel streams: Elapsed time:\t %d ns \t(%f seconds)%n", elapsed, elapsed / Math.pow(10, 9));      
    }.
```

And here are the results for a dual core machine:

```
    Collections: Elapsed time:        94338247 ns   (0,094338 seconds)
    Streams: Elapsed time:           201112924 ns   (0,201113 seconds)
    Parallel streams: Elapsed time:  357243629 ns   (0,357244 seconds)
```

For this particular test, streams are about twice as slow as collections, and parallelism doesn't help (or either I'm using it the wrong way?).

Questions:

- Is this test fair? Have I made any mistake?
- Are streams slower than collections? Has anyone made a good formal benchmark on this?
- Which approach should I strive for?

---

**Updated results.**

I ran the test 1k times after JVM warmup (1k iterations) as advised by @pveentjer:

```
    Collections: Average time:      206884437,000000 ns     (0,206884 seconds)
    Streams: Average time:           98366725,000000 ns     (0,098367 seconds)
    Parallel streams: Average time: 167703705,000000 ns     (0,167704 seconds)
```

In this case streams are more performant. I wonder what would be observed in an app where the filtering function is only called once or twice during runtime.

Comment: have you tried it with an `IntStream` instead?

Comment: Can you please measure properly? If all you are doing is one run, then your benchmarks will of course be off.

Comment: @MisterSmith Can we have some transparency on how you warmed up your JVM, also with 1K tests?

Comment: And for those interested in writting correct microbenchmarks, heres the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java

Comment: @skiwi yes, I've done several tests, warmup iterations in the range of 30 to 1k, showing similar results. How many should I use?

Comment: @MisterSmith 1K should definately suffice.

Comment: @MisterSmith One issue is that `toList` is not parallel, so your parallel stream is actually sequential but you get the overhead of the parallelisation.

Comment: @assylias Using `toList` should run in parallel even if it's collecting to a non-thread-safe list, since the different threads will collect to thread-confined intermediate lists before being merged.

Comment: I'd avoid performing needlessly complex unrelated operations during the benchmark -- the division and square root in this case. It *might* not result in misleading timings but at the very least it scales the measurements in such a way that the actual relevant performance differences appear small.

Comment: @skiwi It's a little funny when people talk about warming up the code. What if the code being tested only runs once in production like happens all the time? This kind of slow down for cold code could be significant enough to justify not using the cleaner `Stream` code and instead use an old-fashioned `for`.

Answer (score 225):

1. Stop using `LinkedList` for anything but heavy removing from the middle of the list using iterator.
2. Stop writing benchmarking code by hand, use [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/).

Proper benchmarks:

```
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OperationsPerInvocation(StreamVsVanilla.N)
public class StreamVsVanilla {
    public static final int N = 10000;

    static List<Integer> sourceList = new ArrayList<>();
    static {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            sourceList.add(i);
        }
    }

    @Benchmark
    public List<Double> vanilla() {
        List<Double> result = new ArrayList<>(sourceList.size() / 2 + 1);
        for (Integer i : sourceList) {
            if (i % 2 == 0){
                result.add(Math.sqrt(i));
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Benchmark
    public List<Double> stream() {
        return sourceList.stream()
                .filter(i -> i % 2 == 0)
                .map(Math::sqrt)
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(
                    () -> new ArrayList<>(sourceList.size() / 2 + 1)));
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Benchmark                   Mode   Samples         Mean   Mean error    Units
StreamVsVanilla.stream      avgt        10       17.588        0.230    ns/op
StreamVsVanilla.vanilla     avgt        10       10.796        0.063    ns/op
```

Just as I expected stream implementation is fairly slower. JIT is able to inline all lambda stuff but doesn't produce as perfectly concise code as vanilla version.

Generally, Java 8 streams are not magic. They couldn't speedup already well-implemented things (with, probably, plain iterations or Java 5's for-each statements replaced with `Iterable.forEach()` and `Collection.removeIf()` calls). Streams are more about coding convenience and safety. Convenience -- speed tradeoff is working here.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to bench this. I don't think changing LinkedList for ArrayList would change anything, as both tests should add to it, the times should not be affected. Anyway, could you please explain the results? It's hard to tell what you are measuring here (units say ns/op, but what is considered an op?).

Comment: @MisterSmith `LinkedList` is slower. op is one iteration.

Comment: Thanks. Still 10-20 ns per iteration is too little compared to the times I obtained.

Comment: Sorry for pesting you, but how comes your times are 10-20 ns when my times were 10-20 ms. Is your computer that fast? And I'm also puzzled by the fact your times are proportional to my first naive (and allegedly invalid) benchmark. So my second benchmark is worse than the first one?

Comment: @MisterSmith look closely at `@OperationsPerInvocation(StreamVsVanilla.N)`. I meausere processing of one list element.

Comment: Your conclusion about performance, while valid, is overblown.  There are plenty of cases where the stream code is *faster* than the iterative code, largely because per-element access costs is cheaper with streams than with plain iterators.  And in many cases, the streams version inlines to something that is equivalent to the hand-written version.  Of course, the devil is in the details; any given bit of code might behave differently.

Comment: @BrianGoetz, could you please specify use cases, when streams are faster?

Comment: In the last version of FMH :use `@Benchmark` instead of `@GenerateMicroBenchmark`

Comment: @BrianGoetz, Could you specify use cases, when Streams are faster?

Comment: [here](https://github.com/mageddo/java-examples/tree/25dbfe05/jmh-benchmark-samples) a example of how generate benchmarks with gradle

Comment: @Alexandr as you asked, this below lambda single line code is much faster than traditional loops. I personally did experiment using JMH and was amazed over the results. ```DATA_FOR_TESTING.stream().peek(s -> bh.consume(s));```
Check out this link for how the above code was written in another iteration methods https://mkyong.com/java/java-jmh-benchmark-tutorial/

Comment: @HariBharathi Are you aware of what `peek` does?

Comment: I couldn't read past your first line. Your statement about using LinkedList is insanely wrong...and then your example uses ArrayList...Um...no. In the production world, LinkedList ends up being far more useful than an ArrayList ever does. If I'm using a List in the first place, then 90 percent of the time I don't need to access any specific index of the list and need the entire thing in iterator order. I very rarely find myself using a List AND needing an ArrayList over LinkedList. And if I find myself needing a particular index, I'm usually better off with Map (except for indexed retrieval)

Comment: @searchengine27 ArrayLists are a lot faster even for sequential access (because of contiguous memory storage an therefore better cache usage). Bjarne Stroustrup (the inventor of C++) about why you should avoid linked lists with modern hardware: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQs6IC-vgmo&t=211s ; here are some direct performance comparisons: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TJHgp1ugKGM&t=2948s

Comment: @J.Coenen Again, you're talking about a very specific usecase and I'm saying thats ridiculous to even be in a position to have such a need (90 percent of cases). That's like saying: "If you were to be in a muddy area 40 miles away from civilization your little hatchback would not be able to move. Clearly everyone should drive massive AWD trucks or just buy a tracked vehicle." Your conclusion is faulty because it's derived from a faulty premise.

Answer (score 19):

1) You see time less than 1 second using you benchmark. That means there can be strong influence of side effects on your results. So, I increased your task 10 times

```
    int max = 10_000_000;
```

and ran your benchmark. My results:

```
Collections: Elapsed time:   8592999350 ns  (8.592999 seconds)
Streams: Elapsed time:       2068208058 ns  (2.068208 seconds)
Parallel streams: Elapsed time:  7186967071 ns  (7.186967 seconds)
```

without edit (`int max = 1_000_000`) results were

```
Collections: Elapsed time:   113373057 ns   (0.113373 seconds)
Streams: Elapsed time:       135570440 ns   (0.135570 seconds)
Parallel streams: Elapsed time:  104091980 ns   (0.104092 seconds)
```

It's like your results: stream is slower than collection. **Conclusion:** much time were spent for stream initialization/values transmitting.

2) After increasing task stream became faster (that's OK), but parallel stream remained too slow. What's wrong? Note: you have `collect(Collectors.toList())` in you command. Collecting to single collection essentially introduces performance bottleneck and overhead in case of concurrent execution. It is possible to estimate the relative cost of overhead by replacing

```
collecting to collection -> counting the element count
```

For streams it can be done by `collect(Collectors.counting())`. I got results:

```
Collections: Elapsed time:   41856183 ns    (0.041856 seconds)
Streams: Elapsed time:       546590322 ns   (0.546590 seconds)
Parallel streams: Elapsed time:  1540051478 ns  (1.540051 seconds)
```

That' s for a big task! (`int max = 10000000`) **Conclusion:** collecting items to collection took majority of time. The slowest part is adding to list. BTW, simple `ArrayList` is used for `Collectors.toList()`.

Comment: You need to microbenchmark this test, meaning it should be first warmed up a lot of times, and then executed a lot of tmes and averaged.

Comment: @skiwi sure, you're right, especially because there is a large deviations in measurements. I've done only basic investigation and don't pretend results to be precise.

Comment: The JIT in server mode, kicks in after 10k executions. And then it takes some time to compile the code and swap it.

Comment: About this sentence: "_you have `collect(Collectors.toList())` in you command, i.e. **there may be a situation when you need to address single Collection by many threads.**_" I'm almost sure that `toList` collects to *several different* list instances in parallel. Only as the last step in the collection the elements are transferred to one list and then returned. So there should be not synchronisation overhead. This is why collectors have both a supplier, an accumerator and a combiner function. (It could be slow for other reasons, of course.)

Comment: @Lii I think the same way about `collect` implementation here. But in the end several lists should be merged into a single one, and it looks like merging is the most heavy operation in given example.

Comment: Maybe the merging is the most expensive part. But there is no synchronisation going on, is there? Because before merging, one thread should have handed over its list to another thread which merges the two.

Comment: @Lii Well, term 'synchronisation' is possibly too vague if it can cause misunderstanding. Can you offer a better wording?

Comment: Yeah, the term "*synchronisation*" is in Java so strongly connected to synchronized-statements and monitors. Alternative phrasing could maybe be something like this: "*Concurrency overhead, starting and stopping new threads, transferring elements from different lists for each thread to a single result list*".

Comment: But maybe that's not entirely accurate, because this threads are in a pool and don't have to be started and stopped. But in some way the jobs must be handed to the threads and  they must signal in some way when they're done. Maybe that also involves synchronisation, so maybe there is nothing wrong with the original phrasing!

Comment: @Lii thanks, with referring to overhead answer looks more precise. And yes, the whole thread pool start shouldn't take so much time ;-)

Answer (score 5):

For what you are trying to do, I would not use regular java api's anyway. There is a ton of boxing/unboxing going on, so there is a huge performance overhead.

Personally I think that a lot of API designed are crap because they create a lot of object litter.

Try to use a primitive arrays of double/int and try to do it single threaded and see what the performance is.

PS:
You might want to have a look at JMH to take care of doing the benchmark. It takes care of some of the typical pitfalls like warming up the JVM.

Comment: LinkedLists are even worse than ArrayLists because you need to create all the node objects. 

The mod operator also is dog slow. I believe something like 10/15 cycles + it drains the instruction pipeline. 

If you want to do a very fast division by 2, just shift the number 1 bit to the right. These are basic tricks, but I'm sure there are mode advanced tricks to speed things up, but these probably are more problem specific.

Comment: I'm aware of the boxing. This is just an informal benchmark. The idea is to have the same ammount of boxing/unboxing in both the collections and the streams tests.

Comment: First I would make sure that it isn't measuring mistake. Try to run the benchmark a few times before you are doing the real benchmark. Then at least you have the JVM warmup out of the way and the code is correctly JITTED. Without this, you probably make the wrong conclusions.

Comment: Ok, i'll post new results following your advice. I've had a look at JMH but it requires Maven and it takes some time to config. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I think it's best to avoid thinking of benchmark tests in terms of "For what you are trying to do." i.e., usually these kinds of exercises are simplified enough to be demonstrable, but complex enough that they look like they can/should be simplified.

Comment: If you want to do a comparison, you are doing a benchmark. End of story.

Comment: I strongly recommend using JMH. If you don't want to use maven, you can download the jar directly (plus a couple dependent jars) and run it using an ant task. It should take ten minutes to set up.

Answer (score 5):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Calculating square root of even numbers from 1 to N       
    int min = 1;
    int max = 10000000;

    List<Integer> sourceList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = min; i < max; i++) {
        sourceList.add(i);
    }

    List<Double> result = new LinkedList<>();


    //Collections approach
    long t0 = System.nanoTime();
    long elapsed = 0;
    for (Integer i : sourceList) {
        if(i % 2 == 0){
            result.add( doSomeCalculate(i));
        }
    }
    elapsed = System.nanoTime() - t0;       
    System.out.printf("Collections: Elapsed time:\t %d ns \t(%f seconds)%n", elapsed, elapsed / Math.pow(10, 9));


    //Stream approach
    Stream<Integer> stream = sourceList.stream();       
    t0 = System.nanoTime();
    result = stream.filter(i -> i%2 == 0).map(i -> doSomeCalculate(i))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    elapsed = System.nanoTime() - t0;       
    System.out.printf("Streams: Elapsed time:\t\t %d ns \t(%f seconds)%n", elapsed, elapsed / Math.pow(10, 9));


    //Parallel stream approach
    stream = sourceList.stream().parallel();        
    t0 = System.nanoTime();
    result = stream.filter(i -> i%2 == 0).map(i ->  doSomeCalculate(i))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    elapsed = System.nanoTime() - t0;       
    System.out.printf("Parallel streams: Elapsed time:\t %d ns \t(%f seconds)%n", elapsed, elapsed / Math.pow(10, 9));      
}

static double doSomeCalculate(int input) {
    for(int i=0; i<100000; i++){
        Math.sqrt(i+input);
    }
    return Math.sqrt(input);
}
```

I change the code a bit, ran on my mac book pro which has 8 cores, I got a reasonable result:

```
Collections: Elapsed time:      1522036826 ns   (1.522037 seconds)
Streams: Elapsed time:          4315833719 ns   (4.315834 seconds)
Parallel streams: Elapsed time:  261152901 ns   (0.261153 seconds)
```

Comment: I think your test is fair, you just need a machine has more cpu cores.

Answer (score 3):

Interesting results for Java 8 and Java 11. I used the code, provided by leventov with little modification:

```
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OperationsPerInvocation(BenchmarkMain.N)
public class BenchmarkMain {

    public static final int N = 10000;

    static List<Integer> sourceList = new ArrayList<>();
    static {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            sourceList.add(i);
        }
    }

    @Benchmark
    public List<Double> vanilla() {
        List<Double> result = new ArrayList<>(sourceList.size() / 2 + 1);
        for (Integer i : sourceList) {
            if (i % 2 == 0){
                result.add(Math.sqrt(i));
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Benchmark
    public List<Double> stream() {
        return sourceList.stream()
                .filter(i -> i % 2 == 0)
                .map(Math::sqrt)
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(
                    () -> new ArrayList<>(sourceList.size() / 2 + 1)));
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        org.openjdk.jmh.Main.main(args);

    }

}
```

Java 8:

```
# JMH version: 1.31
# VM version: JDK 1.8.0_262, OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, 25.262-b19
# VM invoker: /opt/jdk1.8.0_262/jre/bin/java
# VM options: <none>
# Blackhole mode: full + dont-inline hint
# Warmup: 5 iterations, 10 s each
# Measurement: 5 iterations, 10 s each
# Timeout: 10 min per iteration
# Threads: 1 thread, will synchronize iterations
# Benchmark mode: Average time, time/op
...
Benchmark              Mode  Cnt   Score   Error  Units
BenchmarkMain.stream   avgt   25  10.680 ± 0.744  ns/op
BenchmarkMain.vanilla  avgt   25   6.490 ± 0.159  ns/op
```

Java 11:

```
# JMH version: 1.31
# VM version: JDK 11.0.2, OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, 11.0.2+9
# VM invoker: /opt/jdk-11.0.2/bin/java
# VM options: <none>
# Blackhole mode: full + dont-inline hint
# Warmup: 5 iterations, 10 s each
# Measurement: 5 iterations, 10 s each
# Timeout: 10 min per iteration
# Threads: 1 thread, will synchronize iterations
# Benchmark mode: Average time, time/op
...
Benchmark              Mode  Cnt  Score   Error  Units
BenchmarkMain.stream   avgt   25  5.521 ± 0.057  ns/op
BenchmarkMain.vanilla  avgt   25  7.359 ± 0.118  ns/op
```

Answer (score 0):

Used Java 17 My Results

```
Collections: Elapsed time:109585000 ns  (0.109585 seconds)
Streams: Elapsed time:42179700 ns   (0.042180 seconds)
Parallel streams: Elapsed time:76177100 ns  (0.076177 seconds)
```

instead of LinkedList used `List.of` result changed

```
Collections: Elapsed time:49681300 ns   (0.049681 seconds)
Streams: Elapsed time:38930300 ns   (0.038930 seconds)
Parallel streams: Elapsed time:49190500 ns  (0.049191 seconds)
```