# Performance Tuning Libraries and Java 8 Stream Libraries

Tags: java, performance, collections

There are lots of java third party libraries are available for provide high performance in Java Collection. According to this DZONE [Article](http://java.dzone.com/articles/high-performance-libraries), there are some native libraries that follow OSGI model and provide high performance in Java Collection or also perform some others action. Now in `Java 8` the `Streams` are launched for provide good performance in collection libraries and we also perform some parallel actions using `Streams`. Now, Following are my questions:

1. Is Java Streams have better performance then third party libraries like `Trove`, `Javolution` etc.
2. Is is possible to use `Java 8 Streams` with other collection libraries ?

Comment: That is a list of 4 questions. Please ask them separately. The first and third are likely off topic as a request for a library recommendation. The second and fourth are too vague.

Answer (score 3):

1. Trove primitive collections even not a part of Java Collections Framework (the don't implement `Collection`, `List`, `Map` intefraces), though it doesn't prevent them from providing streams API in principle.
2. Trove, Javalution and most other collection libs I'm keeping track of don't support efficient stream implementations yet. They don't override `spliterator()` method to return a `Spliterator` implementation which should override `trySplit()` method to take advantage of parallel stream features.
3. As I mentioned here: [Java 8: performance of Streams vs Collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22658322/java-8-performance-of-streams-vs-collections/22670380#22670380) Streams are not a silver performance bullet, they may significantly help only if you haven't processed your *huge* collections in parallel *yet*, but don't have obstacles to do it using parallel streams.