# How to use collect call in Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collect

Lets say we have this boring piece of code that we all had to use:

```
ArrayList<Long> ids = new ArrayList<Long>();
for (MyObj obj : myList){
    ids.add(obj.getId());
}
```

After switching to Java 8, my IDE is telling me that I can replace this code with `collect call`, and it auto-generates:

```
ArrayList<Long> ids = myList.stream().map(MyObj::getId).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

However its giving me this error:

> collect(java.util.stream.Collector) in Steam cannot be applied to: (java.util.stream.Collector, capture, java.util.List>)

I tried casting the parameter but its giving me undefined `A` and `R`, and the IDE isn't giving any more suggestions.

I'm curious as how can you use `collect call` in this scenario, and I couldn't find any information that could guide me properly. Can anyone shed a light?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The issue is that [`Collectors.toList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--), not surprisingly, returns a `List<T>`. Not an `ArrayList`.

```
List<Long> ids = remove.stream()
        .map(MyObj::getId)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Program to the `interface`.**

From the documentation:

> Returns a `Collector` that accumulates the input elements into a new
>   `List`. There are **no guarantees on the type, mutability,
>   serializability, or thread-safety of the `List` returned**; if more
>   control over the returned List is required, use
>   `toCollection(Supplier)`.

Emphasis mine - you cannot even assume that the `List` returned is mutable, let alone that it is of a specific class. If you want an `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList<Long> ids = remove.stream()
        .map(MyObj::getId)
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Note also, that it is customary to use `import static` with the Java 8 `Stream` API so adding:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toCollection;
```

(I hate starred `import static`, it does nothing but pollute the namespace and add confusion. But selective `import static`, especially with the Java 8 utility classes, can greatly reduce redundant code)

Would result in:

```
ArrayList<Long> ids = remove.stream()
        .map(MyObj::getId)
        .collect(toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Comment: Actually the result code is not any shorter or much more meaningful than what we did before Java8, hmm what about performance??

Comment: @Bludream it's not about it being shorter or more meaningful, it's about introducing a new paradigm to Java - functional programming. This allows you to do things in a very different way to previous iterations of Java. Functional programming comes into its own when you need to abstract _behaviour_ rather than _data_. Further, this above could be a slightly long one-liner; it was certainly not possible to do this in one line previously.

Comment: I see, But like the OP I was also looking for something to replace my collectors spreading everywhere in my code.

Comment: @Bludream the OP was looking to assign the result of a `collect` operation to an `ArrayList` - I don't see anything regarding the spreading of collectors. I'm not even entirely sure what that means...

Comment: well, the first lines of code in the question where you create an empty array and fill it using a loop are known as `collector` blocks.

Comment: @Bludream depending on what you are doing, you might very well be better off using [Guava classes](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.html) in combination with lambdas to provide _views_ on your collections rather than copying them.

Comment: would you take a look at my edited answer?? any comment?

Answer (score 2):

I use a lot of collector blocks where I create an empty Array and fill it using a loop so I decided I need a utility class of my own not to write the same lines again ad again, here it is:

```
public class Collections {

    public static <T, O> List<T> collect(Set<O> items, Function<? super O, ? extends T> mapper) {

    return items.stream().map(mapper).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
}
```

}

and use it like this

```
List<Product> prods = Collections.collect(basket.getOrderItems(), OrderItem::getProduct);
```

or like this

```
List<Long> prods = Collections.collect(basket.getOrderItems(), (item)->item.getProduct().getId());
```

Though it might look like much more easier to read, it seems streams are a little slower in these kind of scenarios, [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22658322/java-8-performance-of-streams-vs-collections)

Comment: You can use `Item::getProduct`. Learning to use method references properly is an important part of learning Java 8. Adding an `import static` also removes the need for referencing the method directly.

Comment: yes, thanks! I got it working the way you said, and I hate using `import static` too!