# How is used the third parameter (combiner) of collect method?

Tags: java, lambda

I'm learning about lambda expressions.
From a list of people, I want another list with the people who are older than 20 years.

```
final List<Person> people = Arrays.asList(
        new Person("John", 10),
        new Person("Greg", 30),
        new Person("Sara", 20),
        new Person("Jane", 15));

 List<Person> olderThan20 =
        people.stream()
       .filter(person -> person.getAge() > 20)
                    .collect(ArrayList::new, 
                             ArrayList::add, 
                             ArrayList::addAll);
```

I have the impression that only the first two parameters are sufficient `ArrayList::new` and                              `ArrayList::add`.

How and when is used the third parameter `ArrayList::addAll` on my exemple?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29959795/how-does-combiner-in-stream-collect-method-work-in-java-8

Comment: @GhostCat I tried to delete my question because it is duplicate. Your solution is ok for me. I know that is the better way to create another list, I just did this exemple for learning propose.

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled ... there is no *need* to delete duplicated questions. And honestly. And even answers on closed-as-dup sometimes help future readers ;-) ... and given the fact how many low quality Q/Ss show up here all day long, why bother about the good content here ;-) x2

Comment: @Eran https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31533316/about-collect-supplier-accumulator-combiner :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "correct" answer for this problem: to use `collect(Collectors.toList())`. There is simply no sense in using the 3 arg version of `collect()` unless you have to. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26905312/how-to-use-collect-call-in-java-8) for more details.

For how to use that 3 arg `collect()`, start reading [here](https://winterbe.com/posts/2014/07/31/java8-stream-tutorial-examples/#collect).

Comment: The closest you can get to needing an additional parameter for this is probably something like `collect(toCollection(CopyOnWriteArrayList::new))`.