# Which is efficient and better approach btw filter and for loop

Tags: java, performance, for-loop, filter, resources

I have a list of Class Object in NamAryVar
I need check if String is equals to any NamVar of NamCls in the list.
I am doing this in two ways and I get the desired result.
But
I want to know which is faster, more efficient and uses less ressources in these two methods.

|*| Using for loop :

```
boolean FndResVab = false;
for(NamCls NamObjIdxVar : NamAryVar)
{
    if(NamObjIdxVar.NamVar.equals("SomString"))
    {
        FndDupVab = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

|O| Using List Filter :

```
Boolean FndResVab = NamAryVar.stream()
                        .filter(IdxVar -> IdxVar.NamVar.equals("SomString"))
                        .count() == 1;

if(FndResVab)
{
    // TskTdo :=> When Found
}
else
{
    // TskTdo :=> When Not Found
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java 8 streams will almost always perform worst than regular iteration. The streams were added to Java to bring functional programming constructs into the language which would in-turn provide convenience to the programmers. Ease of use and maintainability are the primary motivators behind streams.

Have a look at this article: [How Java 8 Lambdas and Streams Can Make Your Code 5 Times Slower](https://dzone.com/articles/do-not-publish-until-12082015how-java-8-lambdas-an)

And this question: [Java 8: performance of Streams vs Collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22658322/java-8-performance-of-streams-vs-collections)