# 3 nested for-each loops as Java stream

Tags: java, java-stream, nested-loops

On the project I am currently working on, we have this construct of three nested for loops:

```java
final Vector3i startPos = new Vector3i(-3, -2, -3);
final Vector3i finishPos = new Vector3i(3, 4, 3);
final Vector3i currentPos = entity.getPos();
  
final List<Vector3i> entityFinderZone = new ArrayList<>();

for (int x = startPos.getX(); x <= finishPos.getX(); x++)
{
    for (int y = startPos.getY(); y <= finishPos.getY(); y++)
    {
        for (int z = startPos.getX(); z <= finishPos.getZ(); z++)
        {
            Vector3i newPos = currentPos.offset(x ,y ,z);
            if (newPos.getX() == 0 && newPos.getZ() == 0 && (newPos.getY() < -1 || newPos.getY() > 2))
            {
                entityFinderZone.add(newPos);
            }
         }
    }
}
```

I would like to do all this with streams to make it faster, but I get an error.

```
final IntStream xCoords = IntStream.iterate(startPos.getX(), i -> i <= finishPos.getX(), i -> i + 1);
final IntStream yCoords = IntStream.iterate(startPos.getY(), i -> i <= finishPos.getY(), i -> i + 1);
final IntStream zCoords = IntStream.iterate(startPos.getZ(), i -> i <= finishPos.getZ(), i -> i + 1);        

entityFinderZone = xCoords.
                flatMap( x -> yCoords.
                        flatMap(y -> zCoords.
                                flatMap(z -> currentPos.offset(x, y, z)))).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Error:

```
Bad return type in lambda expression: Vector3i cannot be converted to int
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: z -> currentPos.offset(x, y, z))) is a Vector, right

Comment: What's the type of `blockFinderZone`?

Comment: _I would like to do all this with streams to make it faster_ It would, if anything, be slower. If you are operating under the assumption 'streams are always better' - no. They are a tool in the toolbox. Currently, an overhyped and overused tool.

Comment: @rzwitserloot thats true. its a false assumption that it is alwas fast: it depends! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22658322/java-8-performance-of-streams-vs-collections

Comment: @DanGetz it's just list<Vector3i>

Comment: @user85421 yep, you right. This was just mistake, when I writing the code and fixed already. Anyway, thanks for noticing

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to do all this with streams to make it faster

Okay. I am going to interpret your question as 'how do I make this faster'.

For starters; **Not** by using lambdas. That doesn't make anything faster. Lambdas, optimally, let you somewhat more easily parallelize a task, but this doesn't come for free, and almost always if a task is so performance crucial that it must be parallelized, you want to control that process and not just ask streams nicely to try its best (which is all you can do - no guarantees and no particular structure on how it does it).

In general 'I will use lambdas because they are faster' is an incorrect mindset.

In general 'I will use lambdas because they are better' is an incorrect mindset.

The right mindset is: "I could do this with lambdas. If I can foresee that the code will be easier to read and easier to maintain on its face (i.e. not with circular reasoning such as 'everybody knows lambdas are easier to read, therefore using lambdas will make this easier to read, QED') - then I shall use them. If not, I won't".

> `if (newPos.getX() == 0 && newPos.getZ() == 0 && (newPos.getY() < -1 || newPos.getZ() > 2))`

triple loops makes this incredibly inefficient if this is all you want to do.

Your loop does -nothing- if this `if` doesn't trigger. Looking at just the if, we have a few boolean properties:

- For either one or zero numbers in the range `[startPos.x, finishPos.x]`, the x offset of `[startPos.x, finishPos.x]` (which is constant for the function) is 0. If there is no such number then this method **does nothing** and the fastest way we can 'do nothing' is to return as fast as we can. Otherwise, there is absolutely no point in looping through `startPos.x-finishPos.x` - nothing happens except for that one number.
- The exact same logic applies to `[startPos.z, finishPos.z]` range.
- For the `y` component, `newPos.getZ() > 2` cannot possibly be true - after all, newPos.getZ() had to be `0` or we wouldn't even have gotten here. `&&` means AND: *All 3 of the conditions have to hold*. Hence that boils down to `newPos.getY() < -1`, which meanas there's a subrange of `[startPos.y, endPos.y]`. We do have to loop - we can possibly reduce the size of that loop some.

That makes your 3-deep loop **a 1 deep loop** which is vastly more efficient. That's how you make this faster. Replacing one code construct with another makes no algorithmic complexity difference whatsoever and indeed doesn't even get you a constant (i.e. mostly irrelevant, but still) speed boost - if anything, it'll slow things down.

### Yay, so how do I make this faster?

1. Calculate the singular x value in the range that would make newPos's x component 0. This is a simple addition/subtraction and then a range check. *Does not involve any loop whatsoever*.
2. Do the same for z.
3. Now loop, only for `y`. Once y goes 'out of range' (`newPos.getY()` is 0 or up), break out - it's never going to fall back into range anyway.

Use basic loops (no lambdas), these things are all much simpler that way.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```java
final List<Vector3i> entityFinderZone = new ArrayList<>();
IntStream.rangeClosed(startPos.getX(), finishPos.getX())
         .forEach(x -> IntStream.rangeClosed(startPos.getY(), finishPos.getY())
                                .forEach(y -> IntStream.rangeClosed(startPos.getZ(), finishPos.getZ())
                                                       .forEach(
                                                           z -> {
                                                               Vector3i newPos = currentPos.offset(x, y, z);
                                                               if (newPos.getX() == 0 && newPos.getZ() == 0 && (newPos.getY() < -1 || newPos.getY() > 2))
                                                                   entityFinderZone.add(newPos);
                                                           })));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing two issues with your code here.

First, you're reusing the `yCoords` and `zCoords` streams, which isn't allowed since the stream will be exhausted after being traversed the second time.  You need to construct a new stream within each nested stream, rather than reusing the same stream instances.

```java
IntStream.iterate(startPos.getX(), i -> i <= finishPos.getX(), i -> i + 1)
        .flatMap(x -> IntStream.iterate(startPos.getY(), i -> i <= finishPos.getY(), i -> i + 1)
                .flatMap(y -> IntStream.iterate(startPos.getZ(), i -> i <= finishPos.getZ(), i -> i + 1)))
```

Second, and what is causing the compilation error you see, is that (assuming `Vector3i.offset` returns another `Vector31` instance) you're attempting to map an `IntStream` elements to non-int `Object` elements using [`IntStream.flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#flatMap(java.util.function.IntFunction)).  However, the [`IntFunction`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/IntFunction.html) used by `flatMap` must return an `int`, after which `flatMap` returns another `IntStream`.

To convert an `IntStream` (with `int` elements) to a `Stream` (with `Object` elements), the [`IntStream.mapToObj`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#mapToObj(java.util.function.IntFunction)) method can be used.  There isn't a `flatMapToObj` method, so the flat mapping would need to be done in a separate step.

Here's a solution using `mapToObj`:

```java
List<Vector3i> entityFinderZone =
        IntStream.iterate(startPos.getX(), i -> i <= finishPos.getX(), i -> i + 1)
                .mapToObj(x -> IntStream.iterate(startPos.getY(), i -> i <= finishPos.getY(), i -> i + 1)
                        .mapToObj(y -> IntStream.iterate(startPos.getZ(), i -> i <= finishPos.getZ(), i -> i + 1)
                                .mapToObj(z -> currentPos.offset(x, y, z)))
                        .flatMap(Function.identity()))
                .flatMap(Function.identity())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Alternatively, the `IntStream` can be converted to a `Stream<Integer>` using the [`IntStream.boxed`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#boxed()) method, and your existing `flatMap` implementation can be used as-is (after fixing the stream reuse issue).  It might or might not be noticeably less efficient to convert to `Integer` objects rather than `int` primitives directly.

```java
List<Vector3i> entityFinderZone =
        IntStream.iterate(startPos.getX(), i -> i <= finishPos.getX(), i -> i + 1)
                .boxed()
                .flatMap(x -> IntStream.iterate(startPos.getY(), i -> i <= finishPos.getY(), i -> i + 1)
                        .boxed()
                        .flatMap(y -> IntStream.iterate(startPos.getZ(), i -> i <= finishPos.getZ(), i -> i + 1)
                                .boxed()
                                .map(z -> currentPos.offset(x, y, z))))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you are trying to add `newPos` (which is of type `Vector3i`) to the `entityFinderZone` list, which is expecting elements of type int.

To fix this error, you can modify the lambda expression to extract the desired values from newPos and add them to the list. Here's an updated version of the code:

```
    for (int x = startPos.getX(); x <= finishPos.getX(); x++) {  
        for (int y = startPos.getY(); y <= finishPos.getY(); y++) {  
            for (int z = startPos.getZ(); z <= finishPos.getZ(); z++) {  
                Vector3i newPos = currentPos.offset(x, y, z);  
                if (newPos.getX() == 0 && newPos.getZ() == 0 && (newPos.getY() < -1 || newPos.getZ() > 2)) {  
                    entityFinderZone.add(newPos);  
                }  
            }  
        }
```