# Lambda expression if-else statement

Tags: java

Hello I Just started learning Lambda expressions, how do I write this with Lambda expressions?

```
  public static void greaterThanFive(String str){
    if(str.length() > 5){
        System.out.println("String length is larger than 5 ");
    }else{
        System.err.println("String length less than 5");
    }
```

if it was just an, if statement I could just do this:

```
Predicate<String> greaterThanFive = (s)-> s.length() > 5;
```

But I can't really figure out when it's an if-else statement.

Comment: Like this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/22492361/1743880

Comment: I just want the example I just posted Lamda Expresion. Can't really see what this has to do with the example I have posted.

Comment: Could you post a real example of what you want then? Is it `if (greaterThanFive.test(str)) {... } else {...}`?

Comment: Use ternary operator.

Comment: Tunaki, I can't figure out how to do an Lamda Expression when its if-else statement, so I just want the example in Lamda Expression. YES

Answer (score 0):

```
Comparator<String> c = (String first, String second) -> {
if (first.length() < second.length()) return -1;
else if (first.length() > second.length()) return 1;
else return 0;
};
```

I believe this answers your question. For more info, read Java8 for really impatient. Its a really good book.

Comment: Hmm is it not possible using filter instead of the if statement?

Comment: I believe filter can only be called on a stream and any intermediate operation on a stream results in another stream. So, we may not achieve the desired outcome you are expecting (This is to my knowledge, I'm also learning java).

Answer (score 0):

Using blocks, you can create lambda expressions that have multiple statements or big statements (like an if-else). Example:

```
new Thread( () -> { // Btw, you can use java.lang.Runnable with a lambda
    System.out.println("A wild NEW THREAD appeared!"); // :)
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    System.out.println("Enemy NEW THREAD ran away!");
});
```

This means all you have to do is to enclose that if-else in the block of a lambda:

```
Consumer<String> greaterThanFive = (s) -> {
    // ...
};
```

Note that there's a semicolon after the block.

Comment: Are there more convenient Funktional interface than Predicate for this kind of stuff like comparator?

Comment: It depends. Here, you should use a `Consumer` because the method you're trying to convert into a lambda expression returns `void` (I didn't look at the return type before the edit :/). `Predicate` is for converting methods that return a `boolean`.