# Variable initialization from intermediate result

Tags: java

Sometimes, when source code gets complicated, I find it confusing to read statements like these:

```
Set<Integer> odds = new HashSet<>(ints); // not yet true
odds.removeAll(evens); // now it's true
```

I was wondering if there's a clever way to avoid a line where `odds` contains also even values. Something similar to this:

```
(Set<Integer> odds = new HashSet<>(ints)).removeAll(evens); // doesn't compile
```

I could use double brace initialization,

```
Set<Integer> odds = new HashSet<Integer>(ints) {{ removeAll(evens); }};
```

but that's obviously bad [for multiple reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958636/what-is-double-brace-initialization-in-java).

Here's another <s>example</s> hack that compiles, but it looks more like a joke:

```
Set<Integer> odds = (odds = new HashSet<>(ints)).retainAll(evens) ? odds : odds
```

The last one that came to my mind (while writing this) seems to be ok, although it uses two lines:

```
Set<Integer> odds;
(odds = new HashSet<Integer>(ints)).removeAll(evens);
```

Any other ideas?

Comment: Wouldn't `Set<Integer> odds = (new HashSet<>(ints)).removeAll(evens);` work  ?

Comment: @Berger no, `removeAll` is void.

Comment: I've seen this described as "temporal coupling"

Answer (score 3):

Use a stream:

```
Set<Integer> odds =
    ints.stream().filter(x -> x % 2 == 1).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

If you want to partition the set into odds and evens at the same time:

```
Map<Boolean, Set<Integer>> oddsAndEvens =
    ints.stream().collect(
        Collectors.partitioningBy(x -> x % 2 == 0, Collectors.toSet()));
Set<Integer> evens = oddsAndEvens.get(true);
Set<Integer> odds = oddsAndEvens.get(false);
```

Comment: At least for a `retainAll()` operation I think this is a good approach: `ints.stream().filter(evens::contains).collect(Collectors.toSet())`.

Comment: @steffen that assumes that you're able to build `evens`; and then surely you've got the same problem in constructing that.

Comment: @AndyTurner In the examples we also do have `evens` already, so that makes no difference. Actually I find your answer helpful, I just wanted to add that a method reference could be a bit less unclear as mud as @Michael put it. For `removeAll()`, we'd need [to negate the predicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21488056/how-to-negate-a-method-reference-predicate).

Comment: While this addresses the odd/even case, what about the *generic case* where you want to create a new set from the substraction of one set from another set (all in a single line)?

Comment: @Michael I find this approach more generic since you can define the result yourself, be it by filtering with predicates like contains, or by a limitation (first random 5) or by element transformation.

Comment: @Michael `ints.stream().filter(x -> !evens.contains(x)).collect(Collectors.toSet())`.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure why do you are trying to over complicate the matter. Provided you can get hold of the collection of `evens`, you can surely do the same for `odds`.

Then you can simply do:

```
Set<Integer> oddsSet = new HashSet<>(odds);
```

Alternatively, you could squeeze your last example into a single line:

```
Set<Integer> odds; (odds = new HashSet<Integer>(ints)).removeAll(evens);
```

I do apologise for my ignorance but I think this problem is of an academic nature and the other suggested answers might not necessarily compensate for not having an extra line at all cost, such as the use of streams will almost certainly underperform against a genuine collection.

Comment: If you disregard the odds and evens, I think it's perfectly reasonable to want to be able to create a `SetC = SetA - SetB` in an idiomatic way

Comment: @Michael I'm not daft and did get the point of the question but thought people would find my answer rather amusing lol; I don't think downvoting was fair.

Comment: Jokey answers should be left in the comments on the question (if at all!). I'm trying to find a source on that, but without much luck. Nothing personal!