# Handling 'not' condition as method reference in stream operation

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, method-reference

I often check if a collection contains an element during stream operations and I write code like this:

```
Set<String> users = ...
Set<String> unemployed = ...

users.stream().filter(unemployedUsers::contains)
```

But I also need to check NOT condition, then  I have to write something like this:

```
users.stream().filter(user -> !unemployedUsers.contains(user))
```

which looks less readable and a bit ugly.

It would be great if I could replace it with something like this:

```
users.stream().filter(not(unemployedUsers::contains))
```

But I haven't found any API in standard lib that allows this.

**Q:** How can I replace lambda expression with method reference when I need to check NOT condition? Or is there any other way that would do the same but **in more elegant way**?

**UPDATE:**
This question duplicates ["How to negate a method reference predicate"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21488056/how-to-negate-a-method-reference-predicate). However is more about how to write NOT operation in **more readable/elegant** way.

I can write custom code like this

```
Predicate<String> not(Predicate<String> predicate) {
    return predicate.negate();
}
```

And use the construction with `not(unemployedUsers::contains)`, but there might be someone who solves this problem in better way.

Comment: FYI, [JDK-8050818](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8050818) covers the addition of a static `Predicate.not(Predicate)` method. But that issue is still open so we'll see this at the earliest in Java 12 (if ever).

Comment: @StefanZobel with the new release cycle it should be available in quite short time. JDK 10 is getting released in March 2018, theoretically 12 will be available in 2019.

Comment: @StefanZobel please post this as an answer - I'll accept.

Comment: Uups, sorry. I meant Java 11 - not 12. Java 10 is already in rampdown phase, so it's quite unlikely that this will get in.

Answer (score 3):

Not so nicely as you might like. The argument to a filter is a [`Predicate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html), and `Predicate` *does* have a [`negate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html#negate--) method. But in order to use it, you would need to cast your argument to a `Predicate`.

```
filter(((Predicate<String>) unemployedUsers::contains).negate())
```

You're probably better off with

```
filter(u -> !unemployedUsers.contains(u))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't without an explicit cast:

```
((Predicate<String>) unemployedUsers::contains).negate())
```

that is because the method reference can potentially be applied to *more* things, not just `Predicate<String>` (could be a `Function<String, Boolean>`)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way. You need to cast the object to the desired class like this:

```
((Predicate<String>) unemployedUsers::contains).negate();
```