# Java lambda intersection two list and remove from result

Tags: java, list, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I want to use Java lambda expression for an intersection of two lists and then ever with lambda expression I want to delete from the list.

Example: I have

```
List<Person> first = new ArrayList<Person>(); 
List<Person> second = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

Suppose that both lists have some Person Object.
I want put into List temp intersection of two list filtered by name for example:

```
List<Person> temp = new ArrayList<>();
for (Person one : first) {
     for (Person two : second) {                        
        if(one.getName.equals(two.getName)) {
                        temp.add(two);
         }
     }
}
```

Then I want to remove some Person from temp using a filter, for example, using the Surname.

```
for (Person tmp : temp) {
     for (Person one : first) {
        if (one.getSurname.equals(tmp.getSurname)) {
              temp.remove(tmp);
        }
     }
}
```

I want to use lambda expression, How i can do?

Answer (score 3):

You may do it like so,

```
Map<String, Set<String>> nameToSurname = second.stream().collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getName, 
            Collectors.mapping(Person::getSurname, Collectors.toSet())));
List<Person> temp = first.stream().
    filter(p -> nameToSurname.containsKey(p.getName()))
    .filter(p -> !nameToSurname.get(p.getName()).contains(p.getSurname()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

First create a `map` from mame to all the `surnames` with that name using the second list. Then iterate over the first list, for each person, check whether there's a value in the map by passing the name as the key. If it does, then check whether the surnames matches that of the current person. If both the criteria are satisfied, then collect it into a container.

Answer (score 3):

Intersection between `first` and `second`:

```
List<Person> intersection = first.stream()
        .filter(p1 -> second.stream().anyMatch(p2 -> p2.getName().equals(p1.getName())))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Remove elements from `myList` based on elements from `first`:

```
first.stream()
    .filter(p1 -> myList.stream().anyMatch(p2 -> p1.getSurName().equals(p2.getSurName())))
    .forEach(myList::remove);
```

Answer (score 1):

Both `for-loop`s might be compressed into two [`Stream::filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) methods:

```
List<Person> temp = second.stream()
    .filter(s ->  first.stream().anyMatch(f -> f.getName().equals(s.getName())))
    .filter(s -> !first.stream().anyMatch(f -> f.getSurame().equals(s.getSurame())))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Lambdas are not always the best solution.

You can use `retainAll` method from `Collection<E>`.

```
fist.retainAll(second);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution by method reference and [`not`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21488056/how-to-negate-a-method-reference-predicate).

```
second.stream()
     .filter(first.stream.map(Person::getName).collect(toSet())::contains)
     .filter(not(first.stream.map(Person::getSurname).collect(toSet())::contains))
     .collect(toList());
```

I didn't write the code in IDE. there may be some compiler errors.