# Java 8 opposite to filter in stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Hello how can I do in java 8 (I know its already in java 11) the opposite to not filter for this

```
filter(date -> date.isEqual(today) && repository.isDateExist(date))
```

I can write like so

```
filter(date -> !date.isEqual(today) || !repository.isDateExist(date))
```

but its hard to read

Comment: `filter(date -> !(date.isEqual(today) && repository.isDateExist(date)))`

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22492361/1746118) is clean enough to implement.

Answer (score 2):

With a condition like

```
filter(date -> date.isEqual(today) && repository.isDateExist(date))
```

the term `repository.isDateExist(date)` is only evaluated when `date` has been proven to be equal to `today`, so its outcome is the same as `repository.isDateExist(today)`, which doesn’t change during the entire stream operation. Hence, there is no reason to repeatedly check that.

So the preferable variant would be

```
final boolean todayExist = repository.isDateExist(today);
…
filter(todayExist? today::isEqual: date -> false)
```

The negation would be

```
final boolean todayExist = repository.isDateExist(today);
…
filter(todayExist? date -> true: date -> !date.isEqual(today))
```

though for this you might consider not applying a filter at all when `todayExist` is `true`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Predicate`'s `negate()` method, but that would require casting the lambda expression to the `Predicate` type. Otherwise the compiler cannot infer the type.

```
filter(((Predicate<Date>)(date -> date.isEqual(today) && repository.isDateExist(date))).negate())
```

Or just assign the `Predicate` to a variable before negating it:

```
Predicate<Date> pred = date -> date.isEqual(today) && repository.isDateExist(date);
filter(pred.negate())
```

Comment: @HadiJ This is Java 8

Comment: @HadiJ The Java-11 version is `Predicate.not`, this is `negate`.