# How to test Predicate with method reference inside forEach of java 8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, method-reference

I am trying out method reference inside forEach

```
private static void printConditionally8(List<Person> people, Predicate<Person> predicate) {
    people.forEach(p-> { if (predicate.test(p)){
        System.out.println("Print here");}
    });
}
```

Above works fine but I want to make it more short using methods reference however its giving compilation problem.Is there any way to make it happen ?

```
private static void printConditionally8(List<Person> people, Predicate<Person> predicate) {
    people.forEach({ if (predicate::test){
        System.out.println("Print here");}
     });
}
```

Comment: I am not sure, but should the P in predicate be capital ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21488056/how-to-negate-a-method-reference-predicate

Comment: Very good question, but I don't know the answer :(

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to filter the list before running your action:

```
people.stream().filter(predicate).forEach(p -> System.out.println("Print here"));
```

You can't use `if(predicate::test)` because `if` takes a boolean expression (the type of `predicate::test` wouldn't even be known here - check lambda expressions' target typing documentation). The only way to make it work would be to invoke the `test()` method as you did it in your first snippet.

Comment: that is perfect approach!! More concise is :  people.stream().filter(predicate).forEach(System.out::println);

Answer (score 1):

I think you use the method reference concept in a wrong way.

Method reference is a nifty syntax for calling a method as if its a lambda (java 8+ will do all the conversions):

Here is an example:

```
public class Foo {



   private static void printConditionally8(List<Person>persons, Predicate<Person> f) {
      persons.stream().filter(f).forEach(p -> System.out.print(p + " is here"));
   }
   private static Boolean myFilter(Person p) {
      return p.age > 18; 
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      List<Person> persons = ... // create a list of persons
      printConditionally8(persons, Foo::myFilter); 
   } 

}
```

Notice how does the main method really call the `printConditionally8`. It passes the reference to the method myFilter as if is an "anonymous class" - that implements the `Predicate` interface.

Comment: We dont need myFilter(Person p) method explicitly here. You can pass lambda directly printConditionally8(persons, p-> p.age > 18);

Comment: Of course you can, but it've assumed that the question is about a difficulty to grasp a concept of method inference that's why I've provided an example like this