# How to: Find the Set Difference Between Two Collections in Java

Tags: java

I am relativly new to Java and I am wondering if there is a method like LINQs "[Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397894.aspx)" in C# to get the different items of two sets.

I looked at `CollectionUtils` from apache common, `Collections` and `Collections2` from guava but found no such method.

Btw: I am using Java 7 not Java 8.

Comment: Are you asking on Java or C#?

Comment: Java has a Set interface which would likely have what you're looking for. If you're simply looking under the Collection area, you might not find it. If you insist on using Collections, you should look at the guava libraries

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza It is quite clear that he is working in Java.

Comment: I think i found was i was looking for it is right on the Sets util class, i was somehow not seeing it in the first place. The method is called "Sets.difference".

Comment: @Rajacsp the dupe you pointed out is old and of lower quality. It does not for example state which language the question is about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used Guava [Sets.difference](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#difference-java.util.Set-java.util.Set-).

The parameters are sets and not general collections, but a handy way to create sets from any collection (with unique items) is Guava [ImmutableSet.copyOf](https://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet.html#copyOf(java.lang.Iterable))(Iterable).

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have:

```
...
Set<int> s1 = new HashSet<Integer>();
Set<int> s2 = new HashSet<Integer>();
...
```

You can try this

```
s2.removeAll(s1);
```

See the doc for [Set#removeAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#removeAll)

**NOTE**: This will modify the set, but you can have a copy of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can Try this

```
collection2.removeAll(collection1);
```

Although this will mutate `collection2`, so create a copy if you need to preserve it.