# ways to find elements in a list in collection framework

Tags: java, collections

Given a list of 100 elements, if I take out 
1 element from list, How will you find out what 
is the element removed?

I have been asked this question in one of my interview.

Comment: Are you given the original list as well as the list with the element deleted?

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919387/how-can-i-calculate-the-difference-between-two-arraylists

Comment: `List` is ordered per the API spec...  So if one `List`, `after`, is really just another `List`, `before` with a single element removed via `List::remove`, you can just iterate through and return the first where `before.get(i) != after.get(i)`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are given different references to the contents of the collection `before` and `after` the deletion of the element, the command

```
before.removeAll(after);
```

will leave `before` with just one element, i.e. the deleted one, if the remaining elements are not equal to the deleted one.

Otherwise, depending on how the deletion is done, you get the removed element either as a parameter to `remove(element)` or as the return value of `remove(elementIndex)`, for collections that support indexed deletion (e.g., subclasses of `List`).

Comment: That works for `Set` but not for `List`. For example if `before` is `[1, 1]` and `after` is `[1]`, then `removeAll` would give `[]`.

Comment: To solve that, parallel iteration, printing and skipping values in `before` that don't match next value in `after`.

Comment: @PaulBoddington Good point, I have updated the answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are given the new collection and the old collection then the simplest mechanism is to remove each item in the new from the old. What is left is the difference between the two.

For example, in Java 8:

```
newCollection.stream().forEach(oldCollection::remove);
```

This works because the `stream` and `remove` methods are both in the `Collection` interface so it should work for all collections that support remove. Because `remove` is called once for each item in `newCollection` only a single instance of each will be removed which helps with duplicate items.

If `remove` is not supported by the collection then a simple solution is to create a new copy before using this method (e.g. `new ArrayList<>(oldCollection)`):

If you are specifically looking for one item in an indexed collection then you can just look for the first one that doesn't match which is much cheaper:

```
IntStream.range(0, oldCollection.size())
    .filter(n -> n >= newCollection.size() 
       || !oldCollection.get(n).equals(newCollection.get(n)))
    .findFirst();
```

This returns an `Optional` to allow for the situation in which no items have been removed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they give you 100 int elements and remove 1 int from the collection. what you can do is to do a sum() for 100 elements and another sum() for the 99 elements. Then you do a subtraction between the two sum and you will get the element that was removed from the collection.

Comment: This only gives you an answer if the collections are numerical (I may have read the question wrong, but I don't think numerical values were specified)

Comment: @BenedictLewis the question itself is not clear.  thats why I was using the word "Assuming".