# Compare two xml and find the missing node using Java

Tags: java, xml, xmlunit

This has been bothering me for days. I just need to find out what are the missing nodes in the second xml by comparison. I tried xmlunit but it doesn't really help me find the missing node since it compares line by line. two sample xml below:
xml1:

```
<test testcase="101">
    <value="1">
    <value="2">
    <value="3">
</test>
```

xml2:

```
<test testcase="101">
    <value="3">
    <value="2">
</test>
```

Note that value=3 is actually there in the second copy it just get to the first node but still I consider it's not missing. how do i find the missing node value="1"?

Comment: You may want to compare `List` of values : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919387/how-can-i-calculate-the-difference-between-two-arraylists

Comment: How big the xml are?

Comment: Also are values in your nodes unique? If so the `Set` might be a better option than `List`.

Comment: it's a relatively  small xml and yes the nodes are supposed to be unique.

Comment: If you tell XMLUnit to match nodes based on their name and the value of the `value` attribute then it should do the trick. See https://github.com/xmlunit/user-guide/wiki/SelectingNodes

Comment: I think this is what I need. you rock man.